# How to check in (or upload) again a solution that i have on my local drive and manually deleted from TFS?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, tfs

I'm using VS2017 and i have a solution on my local drive.

I had the same solution on my TFS as well, but i deleted it from the repository page manually.

Now if i want to check in the solution again i get a 'no pending changes' message, even if the TFS folder is empty.

I tried a few things but nothing seems to work.

I just don't know how to put these files on my TFS again and i can't find the help i need anywhere. Sorry if it's a duplicated question, i just can't find the answer to this.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you are using TFVC;

You need to sync (get latest) your local workplace with the server to see any further changes.

If you want to simply "restore" the solution, you can do an "undelete" through the source control explorer.

If do not want to revert your delete, you can get latest (which will remove any unchanged files) and then copy the "new" files over the same location. You will probably still have to and "Add Files" in the source explorer to re-pend them with TFS and then check them in.

In either case, make a backup of the files you are wanting to retain.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way is creating a branch from a Workspace Version, then check in the branch.

Please follow below steps to do that: (Backup the original project first)

1. Right click the project directory in **Source Control Explorer >
   Branching and Merging > Branch**
2. Select **Workspace Version** for Branch from version By, then click
   **OK**.
3. Check in the new created branch
4. Right click the **Team Project name** in Source Control Explorer and
   **Get Latest Version** to sync delete the original branch (Backup it first).
5. Rename the new created branch to original one if needed.
6. Check in the changes
7. Check the remote server in page site, the project files/code will come
   back.

[image]

Comment: @Emiliano Rodriguez Have you resolved your issue by above workaround? any update for this?